# JModuleHelper::getModule not working?

Tags: php, joomla, module, joomla1.7

I have tried many ways to get it working Joomla 1.7... but I get null returned, I am trying to load some module params into a plugin.

```
    $module = JModuleHelper::getModule('Tilte of my mod');
    $moduleParams = new JRegistry();
    $moduleParams->loadString($module->params);
    $param = $moduleParams->get('category_list');
```

Any Ideas, I have tried many diferent ways...

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something more like:

```
$[parameter-name-in-xml-file] = $params->get('[parameter-name-in-xml-file]', 0);
```